# Print bold letters using EPSON bluetooth printer in Android

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth, epson

This is my full working code

```
public class NewActivity extends Activity{

// will show the statuses like bluetooth open, close or data sent
TextView myLabel;

// will enable user to enter any text to be printed
EditText myTextbox;

// android built in classes for bluetooth operations
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

// needed for communication to bluetooth device / network
OutputStream mmOutputStream;
InputStream mmInputStream;
Thread workerThread;

byte[] readBuffer;
int readBufferPosition;
volatile boolean stopWorker;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.new_main);

    try {
        // more codes will be here
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 // we are going to have three buttons for specific functions
    Button openButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.open);
    Button sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
    Button closeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.close);

    // text label and input box
    myLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label);
    myTextbox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.entry);

 // open bluetooth connection
    openButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                findBT();
                openBT();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

 // send data typed by the user to be printed
    sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                sendData();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

 // close bluetooth connection
    closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                closeBT();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

// close the connection to bluetooth printer.
void closeBT() throws IOException {
    try {
        stopWorker = true;
        mmOutputStream.close();
        mmInputStream.close();
        mmSocket.close();
        myLabel.setText("Bluetooth Closed");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
// this will send text data to be printed by the bluetooth printer
void sendData() throws IOException {
    try {

        Spanned  msg = Html.fromHtml("<h1>My First Example</h1> <p>My first Print.</p> <p><b>This is a paragraph.</b></p>");
        myTextbox.setText(msg, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);

        byte[] arrayOfByte1 = { 27, 33, 0 };
        byte[] format = { 27, 33, 0 };

     // Bold
     format[2] = ((byte)(0x8 | arrayOfByte1[2]));

        mmOutputStream.write(format);
        mmOutputStream.write(msg.toString().getBytes(),0,msg.toString().getBytes().length);

        // tell the user data were sent
        myLabel.setText("Data sent.");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// this will find a bluetooth printer device
void findBT() {

    try {
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        if(mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            myLabel.setText("No bluetooth adapter available");
        }

        if(!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBluetooth = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBluetooth, 0);
        }

        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

        if(pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {

                // RPP300 is the name of the bluetooth printer device
                // we got this name from the list of paired devices
                if (device.getName().equals("TM-P20_002154")) {
                    mmDevice = device;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        myLabel.setText("Bluetooth device found.");

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// tries to open a connection to the bluetooth printer device
void openBT() throws IOException {
    try {

        // Standard SerialPortService ID
        UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
         // UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("fa87c0d0-afac-11de-8a39-0800200c9a66");            
        mmSocket = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
        mmSocket.connect();
        mmOutputStream = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
        mmInputStream = mmSocket.getInputStream();

        beginListenForData();

        myLabel.setText("Bluetooth Opened");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/*
 * after opening a connection to bluetooth printer device,
 * we have to listen and check if a data were sent to be printed.
 */
void beginListenForData() {
    try {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();

        // this is the ASCII code for a newline character
        final byte delimiter = 10;

        stopWorker = false;
        readBufferPosition = 0;
        readBuffer = new byte[1024];

        workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopWorker) {

                    try {

                        int bytesAvailable = mmInputStream.available();

                        if (bytesAvailable > 0) {

                            byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                            mmInputStream.read(packetBytes);

                            for (int i = 0; i < bytesAvailable; i++) {

                                byte b = packetBytes[i];
                                if (b == delimiter) {

                                    byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
                                    System.arraycopy(
                                        readBuffer, 0,
                                        encodedBytes, 0,
                                        encodedBytes.length
                                    );

                                    // specify US-ASCII encoding
                                    final String data = new String(encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");
                                    readBufferPosition = 0;

                                    // tell the user data were sent to bluetooth printer device
                                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                        public void run() {
                                            myLabel.setText(data);
                                        }
                                    });

                                } else {
                                    readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = b;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        stopWorker = true;
                    }

                }
            }
        });

        workerThread.start();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }
  }
```

new_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_margin="10dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Type here:" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/entry"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/label" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/entry" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/open"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:text="Open" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/send"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Send" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/close"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Close" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I am getting html content to string in `EditText` box but while printing  it is taking all as string. I need to print bold letters as in my `EditText` box. Please look at the below screenshots. [image: This is how it prints in my printer]
[image: This is how it looks when I convert html to string]

Answer (score 0):

To print in bold, you must send the escape sequence ESC E n (0x1b, 0x45, n) where n is 1 for emphasized mode, 0 is to turn emphasized mode off.

Comment: this answer is not clear enough i have same issue but cant help it

Comment: Which part don't you understand? You have to send exactly three bytes to the printer to set or unset emphasized mode.